# How to display and not display span tag in react depending on a timer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to display and not display a span tag in my react project, depending on a boolean value I pass in.

Could you help me identify how to pass in a value that I can change from true to false, which will display or not display the span tag.

Furthermore when I tried 2 methods to disable the div and to disable the span tag itself but it is not working.

The intended action I want is to show and not show the smiling emoji depending on boolean value I pass in.

For context, the file is of extension .js I am using React and material-ui

```
<span role='img' aria-label='happy' disabled='true'>
                            
</span>
```

```
<div className='heroTypedElement' style={{ display: false }}>
                                
   <span role='img' aria-label='sheep' disabled='true'>
                                    
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: display: false?, it doesn´t exists, try display:none

Comment: You should use state in React component to show tags depending on boolean value. Showing or not showing decide in React like this `{state.elementShow === true? <tag></tag> : ''}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css

Add these to your css:

```
div.heroTypedElement > span[data-disabled ="true"] {
  display:none
}
div.heroTypedElement > span[data-disabled ="false"] {
  display:inline
}
```

As @cloned pointed out in comments disabled is not span tag so you can make a custom attribute like `data-disabled` and change JSX to this :

```
<span role='img' aria-label='happy' data-disabled='true'>
                            
</span>
```

You can also use ternary operators like below

Here react would check if 'showEmoji' is true then would show the emoji, otherwise return empty string.

```
    return(
<div className='heroTypedElement' style={{ display: false }}>
                                
   <span role='img' aria-label='sheep'>
      {showEmoji ?'':''}
   </span>
</div>
)
```

Or you can use && operator :

Here javascript would evaluate showEmoji first. if it's true then would return the second statement without checking because if showEmoji is true then second statement would indicate wether whole check is true or false, and if showEmoji is false then javascript would halt the check because it wont matter wether second statement is true or not

return(
<div className='heroTypedElement' style={{ display: false }}>

```
   <span role='img' aria-label='sheep'>
      {showEmoji && ''}
   </span>
</div>
)
```

Comment: `disabled` does not exist on span tag. It will most likely work, but better would be to use data-attribute for this to have valid HTML.

Comment: Great suggestion with the ternary operator.

Comment: @javarunner you can upvote and set this as accepted answer if solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply the condition in the code. it will look something like this:

```
this.state = {
    showSpan:true
}
```

inside return

```
{ this.state.showSpan && <span role='img' aria-label='happy' disabled='true'>
                        
   </span>
}
```

also, make a function which will `setState` `showSpan` true to false and vice versa. This might solve your issue for displaying or not displaying any span or any piece of code conditionally.